# How to force iOS to prompt an authentication popup

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

I'm working on an app that uses touchID. What I want is to accept only 3 touch ID failures (instead of 5, the value used by apple). But I can't manage to make iOS prompt a lockedOut popup (that usually comes with the 5th error) :

[image]
I'm using `evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` from `LAContext` but when prompted before the regular 5, it just ask for the user to use his finger it would normally.

EDIT (rephrase the question) : How can I force iOS to prompt this popup even if its not in a LockedOut state ?

Comment: You can't force that. Why do you want to change what the user has set on their device? Seems like you're trying to fight the system here? Is it really that much of a pain that it allows 5 tries instead of 3?

Comment: That's what I feared, after several tries I couldn't make it happen. I know I'm going against apple's recommandations, but you know, client having its requests ... I'll ask my question differently

Comment: Unless your client has several PHDs in various aspects of computer security I'd politely tell them that Apple has a very secure system that should be left alone and not risk changing any part of it. :-D

Comment: Until iOS9 we could edit the global var `maxBiometryFailures`, which is deprecated now. I guess there's no replacement for that ?